# Currency Exchange Pivot Table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datagridview, pivot-table

I have a pivoted Currency Exchange Table with this stored procedure in the database.

```
USE XXX
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_ExRatesPerDate]    Script Date: 24.11.2015 13:53:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExRatesPerDate] 
    @Month int,
    @Year int
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT a.Currency_CODE as '\',b.ToCurrency as CUR,ISNULL(b.Rate,0) as RATES
FROM db_datawriter.ExRatesPerMonth b
INNER JOIN dbo.Currencies a ON a.Currency_CODE=b.FromCurrency
INNER JOIN db_datawriter.ExRatesFixings c ON b.ExRatesFixings_ID=c.ID
WHERE c.Year=@Year AND c.Month=@Month
)as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(RATES) FOR CUR IN 
    (CHF,CNY,CZK,EUR,GBP,HKD,INR,IRR,USD)

)ID
```

Now I want to update the database if the user changes some values in the datagridview

[image: Datagrid View]
[image: Exchange Rates Date And Rate Tables]

How do I update the database tables correctly?

```
 - ID   Rate    FromCurrency    ToCurrency  ExRatesFixings_ID
7   3.00    USD CHF 2
8   2.00    IRR CHF 2
9   0.00    INR CHF 2
10  0.00    HKD CHF 2
11  0.00    GBP CHF 2
12  0.00    EUR CHF 2
13  0.00    CZK CHF 2
14  0.00    CNY CHF 2
15  0.00    CHF CHF 2
16  0.00    USD CNY 2
17  4.00    IRR CNY 2
18  0.00    INR CNY 2
19  0.00    HKD CNY 2
20  0.00    GBP CNY 2
21  0.00    EUR CNY 2
22  0.00    CZK CNY 2
23  0.00    CNY CNY 2
24  0.00    CHF CNY 2
25  0.00    USD CZK 2
26  0.00    IRR CZK 2
27  0.00    INR CZK 2
28  0.00    HKD CZK 2
29  0.00    GBP CZK 2
30  0.00    EUR CZK 2
31  0.00    CZK CZK 2
32  0.00    CNY CZK 2
33  0.00    CHF CZK 2
34  0.00    USD EUR 2
35  0.00    IRR EUR 2
36  0.00    INR EUR 2
37  0.00    HKD EUR 2
38  0.00    GBP EUR 2
39  0.00    EUR EUR 2
40  0.00    CZK EUR 2
41  0.00    CNY EUR 2
42  0.00    CHF EUR 2
43  0.00    USD GBP 2
44  0.00    IRR GBP 2
45  0.00    INR GBP 2
46  0.00    HKD GBP 2
47  0.00    GBP GBP 2
48  0.00    EUR GBP 2
49  0.00    CZK GBP 2
50  0.00    CNY GBP 2
51  0.00    CHF GBP 2
52  0.00    USD HKD 2
53  0.00    IRR HKD 2
54  0.00    INR HKD 2
55  0.00    HKD HKD 2
56  0.00    GBP HKD 2
57  0.00    EUR HKD 2
58  0.00    CZK HKD 2
59  0.00    CNY HKD 2
60  0.00    CHF HKD 2
61  0.00    USD INR 2
62  0.00    IRR INR 2
63  0.00    INR INR 2
64  0.00    HKD INR 2
65  0.00    GBP INR 2
66  0.00    EUR INR 2
67  0.00    CZK INR 2
68  0.00    CNY INR 2
69  0.00    CHF INR 2
70  0.00    USD IRR 2
71  0.00    IRR IRR 2
72  0.00    INR IRR 2
73  0.00    HKD IRR 2
74  0.00    GBP IRR 2
75  0.00    EUR IRR 2
76  0.00    CZK IRR 2
77  0.00    CNY IRR 2
78  0.00    CHF IRR 2
79  0.00    USD USD 2
80  0.00    IRR USD 2
81  0.00    INR USD 2
82  0.00    HKD USD 2
83  0.00    GBP USD 2
84  0.00    EUR USD 2
85  0.00    CZK USD 2
86  0.00    CNY USD 2
87  0.00    CHF USD 2
```

This is the C# Code to Execute the Pivot Procedure:

```
// initialize Member for ExRates
MasterData.dtExRates = new DataTable("ExRates");
MasterData.sqlExRates = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_ExRatesPerDate", MasterData.sqlConn);
MasterData.sqlExRates.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Month", SqlDbType.Int));
MasterData.sqlExRates.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Year", SqlDbType.Int));
MasterData.sqlExRates.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
MasterData.daExRates = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlExRates);
MasterData.daExRates.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_ExRatesPerDate", MasterData.sqlConn);
MasterData.bsExRates = new BindingSource();
```

Comment: With an update statement? As posted there simply isn't enough information to offer any help. Do you need help with the sql or the c# code? Maybe both? What have you tried? Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I made a pivot table in the sql database which is displayed in the datagridview. But the user should be able to change the values. Is it possible to write a sqldataadapter or anything else to commit all changes to the database table that the user has changed. Or even what would be your favorite method to send the information back to the db?

Comment: OK. So...as I said before...do you need help with the sql part? The c# part? both parts? You have to provide some details for somebody to be able to help you.

Comment: I dont need code but a concept (how you personally would start this task) would be great.

Comment: It is a simple update statement. Update [your table] set [YourColumn] = NewVal where FromCurr = FromCurrParameter and ToCurr = ToCurrParameter. Not really sure what else there is to it.

Comment: I dont need code but a concept (how you personally would start this task) would be great. The solution has to meet the following requirements: 1.It should be a nxn Matrix which i already made. 2. the matrix should be displayed in the datagridview 3. if the user changes a value in the datagridview then it should be updated in the database imidiately. :)

Comment: i cant believe that there is no easier way to display a nxn matrix n a datagridview :/ but anyways thanks for you supporting comment

Comment: Well it seems that you have accomplished #1 and #2 so the only piece left is #3 which should be super simple. I guess I missing the point of your question.